# Properties of Gibbs free energy

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium, energy, theoretical-chemistry

I have been asked to find the correct statement/(s) from the below:

$1.$ In any closed system with P, V work only, $G$ is always minimized at equilibrium.

$2.\ ΔG$ is always zero for a reversible process in a closed system.

$3. \ ΔG°$ for an ideal gas is a function of pressure.

$4.$ For an irreversible, isothermal expansion process in a closed system with PV-work only, $ΔG$ must be negative.

The answer: only statment $4$ is correct.

I tried to use Gibbs-Helmholtz equation for $3.$
$$H = -T^2 \left( \frac{\partial (G/T)}{\partial T} \right)$$

and that for a process at equilibrium

$$ΔG° = -RT\ln(K_{\text{eq}})$$

I am still unable to conclude. How to comment about all the statements?

Comment: If this is the only question you get wrong on a test you are fine. I don't know what an isothermal expansion doing P-V work irreversibly is. G is a state function most useful for reactions that reach equilibrium and therefore are reversible. The Second Law removes the deficiency in the First Law that reactions do not go to completion but to equilibrium, the free energy functions.

Comment: The standard change is for a pressure of 1 bar.

Comment: For 1/ and 2/, consider when the Helmholtz energy is used instead of Gibbs energy. For 3/ Consider equation for dependence of Delta G on pressure. What is the constant term at the given temperature?